# Kernel density estimation in seaborn for cyclic end points

Tags: python, seaborn, kernel-density

I've got some data that has cyclic end points (the x-axis is longitude and hence 0 and 360 are the same point), but as far as I can tell [seaborn.kdeplot](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html) doesn't have an option to specify cyclic end points.

What would be the easiest away to do univariate kernel density estimation in python/seaborn whilst accounting for the cyclic end points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the KDE using other libraries, and then just plot them in seaborn.

You can use the `scipy` KDE. It has an option to define cyclic boundary ([link](https://pythonhosted.org/PyQt-Fit/KDE_tut.html#cyclic-boundaries))

If you want more sophisticated KDE kernels (SciPy has only gaussian), you can use the `scikit-learn` KDE with a sphere distance metric ([link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/density.html#density-estimation-histograms)).

Comment: Sphere distance metric (Haversine Metric) requires 2D input data. What about 1D?

Comment: `PyQt-Fit` is not `scipy`.